# Prerequisites to run Web Deployment projects

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-deployment-project

I'm installing a product developped in ASP .NET 3.5 SP1
I made a setup using ASP .NET Web Deployment Project. The Setup runs without any problems on one server, and fails on a freshly installed one.

The .NET 3.5 SP1 framework is installed on a fresh W2k8 Server.

Anyone knows what I should install to get the Setup running?

Comment: Have you checked the installers log and the Application Eventlog? They should help track down the missing component.

Comment: Do you know where I can find the installer log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS PER [STANLEY](http://weblogs.asp.net/stanleygu/archive/2010/04/13/tip-15-deploy-asp-net-3-5-to-windows-server-2008-r2-and-iis-7-5.aspx)

You have ASP.NET 3.5 web application deployed to windows server 2008 R2 and IIS7.5. The physical location of the application is C:\MyWeb. You receive errors when you use IIS Manager to browse the application. The following is the check list that can help you prevent the errors from occurring.

1. Install .NET Framework 3.5 SP1
2. Install IIS 7.5 and ASP.NET
3. Register ASP.NET with IIS
4. Set IIS_IUSRS group permission to allow Modify to the folder C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files
5. Set IIS_IUSRS group permission to allow Modify to the folder C:\Windows\temp if your web application involves WCF Service, XMLSerializer, etc
6. Set IIS_IUSRS group Read permission to the application physical folder C:\MyWeb
7. Set IUSR account Read permission to the application physical  folder C:\MyWeb if Anonymous Authentication is enabled
8. Use Integrated Mode to take advantage of its many benefits and features
9. Move httpModules and httpHandlers from system.web section to Modules and Handlers in system.webServer section of web.config
10. If you want to have an option of using Classic Mode, Do Copy instead of Move in the above step 9 and Add  to the system.webServer section